# What is the distance between A and B

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

I think the answer should be sum of inradius of the two circles, which I am getting as 14. However, it is not in the options. WHY?

Comment: Because the circles don't touch each other.

Comment: Are you sure the circles are touching ? (7secs too late...)

Comment: Of course, they are "nearly" touching, and only one of the four answers is near $14$.  To do it exactly, form the right triangle with hypotenuse $AB$ and legs parallel to $PR$ and $QS$.  The horizontal leg has length $14$ and the vertical has length $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: Do not assume the circles touch. Let the radius of circle $A$ be $a$ and that of $B$ be $b$. Then the horizontal distance between their centres is $b+a$ and the vertical distance $b-a$. The distance between the centres is
$$\sqrt{(b+a)^2+(b-a)^2}=\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}$$
which is *not* $a+b$.